# Which method will be called when UITabelViewCell is no more appear in UItableView

Tags: uitableview

Suppose there are 20 items to display in `UITableView`. At a time 5 `UITableViewCell`  are visible. I am adding **observer** in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`method. Now if user scrolls the table then suppose first row is not visible. So my quesion is how can I remove the observer? Any method will be called when `UITableViewCell` is no more visible in `UITableView`?

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841042/detect-when-uitableviewcell-goes-off-the-screen), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211961/objective-c-is-there-any-event-when-a-table-cell-goes-away) and [here](http://samplecodebank.blogspot.com/2013/06/UITableView-tableView-didEndDisplayingCell-forRowAtIndexPath-example.html) you can find the solutions for your problem.
You should use below `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```